# Bootstrap 3: scrollable column below navigation bar

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this page below:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">

        ......
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>


<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-5" id="column1">
        <!--  Sidebar content SCROLLABLE -->
        ....
        <!-- Sidebar content end> -->
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-7" id="column2">
        <!--  body content FIXED -->
        ....
        <!-- body content end> -->
        </div>
```

The navigation bar is generated by default from Laravel typing from command line "php make:auth"

What I'm trying to achieve is column1 scrollable on the left, and column2 fixed on the right. Both column1 and column2 should start below navigation bar and should reach the end of the window.
I've tried tons of solutions using absolute position, jQuery, or a mix of the two. So far this is the closer workaround I've found: http://jsfiddle.net/vgxvpjdv/3/
But it does not work for xs devices as when the user taps on the button to expand the nav bar (collapsed hamburger), the items overlap the columns below.
This is a scheme of what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: layout scheme]

I would like to keep bootstrap grid classes (if possible) in order to have my columns responsive.

This is the full navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">

            <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <!-- Branding Image -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                Laravel
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
            <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a></li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <!-- Authentication Links -->
                @if (Auth::guest())
                    <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
                @else
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                            {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                @endif
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I've fixed it:

1. navbar fixed to the top

   ```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top sticky">
   ```
2. CSS with the 2 columns below the navbar using fixed position and responsive

   ```
   @media (min-width: 768px) { 
     #column1 {
     position:fixed;
     top:50px;
     left:0;
     overflow-y: scroll;
     height:calc(100% - 50px);
     }
     #column2 {
     position:fixed;
     top:50px;
     right:0px;
     overflow-y: hidden;
     height:calc(100% - 50px);
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the CSS properties 'overflow-y: scroll' and 'overflow-y: fixed'?

This should fix the problem, just give the individual columns class names such as .scrollcontent and .fixedcontent

and in your css give them the overflow properties.

.scrollcontent {
    overflow-y: scroll; //or use auto if there is no need for a scroll
}

Comment: yes I've tried but somehow this ends up having both columns scrollable

Comment: Have you used a class with overflow-y: visible; on the other column?